# jQuery form validation showing Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I am using wordpress. In wordpress I want to live validate a form. So after searching different jQuery form validation I got  http://www.geektantra.com/projects/jquery-form-validate/ link. I used all the source codes in my site. But after all that when I rendered the page I got this errors in my chrome console tab

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate' localhost:70
(anonymous function) localhost:70
o jquery.js:2
p.fireWith jquery.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery.js:2
c.addEventListener.B
```

all of my jquery files are included in header file like this

```
<?php
  wp_enqueue_script('jQuery', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js');
  wp_enqueue_script('Validations', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.validate.js');
  wp_enqueue_script('Validations Function', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/js/jquery.validation.functions.js');
?>
```

and the jQuery code inside head is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#ValidTitle").validate({
        expression: "if (VAL != '0') return true; else return false;",
        message: "Please make a right selection for the title"
    });
    jQuery("#Name").validate({
        expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
        message: "Please enter your name"
    });
    jQuery("#BusinessPhone").validate({
        expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[9][0-9]{9}$/)) return true; else return false;",
        message: "Should be a valid Phone Number"
    });
    jQuery("#ValidEmail").validate({
        expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[^\\W][a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]+([a-zA-Z0-9\\_\\-\\.]+)*\\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/)) return true; else return false;",
        message: "Please enter a valid Email ID"
    });
    jQuery("#NumberOfEmployee").validate({
        expression: "if (!isNaN(VAL) && VAL) return true; else return false;",
        message: "Please enter a valid number of employees"
    });
    jQuery("#ValueSoftware").validate({
        expression: "if (VAL != '0') return true; else return false;",
        message: "Please make a right selection for Value Software"
    });                
    jQuery("#TaxYear").validate({
        expression: "if (VAL != '0') return true; else return false;",
        message: "Please make a selection"
    });
});

</script>
```

Can someone kindly help me how to solve this. It will be really appreciable.

Comment: Have you included the JS plugin file after JQuery?

Comment: also... many wordpress pages end up with multiple versions of jQuerly loading. Make sure only one is present, and is before all plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By going through your error code I think there might be some problems like

- jQuery is not loaded properly in your site
- jQuery framework is loaded after your jQuery plugin

So to check them just go through the page source code i.e `ctrl+u` in your keyboard and please check whether every file is properly  linked with their external file or not. One main thing should be check there is to check jQuery is first loaded then after your jQuery Plugin has been loaded.

Hope these steps will help you to check the error.